How to construct an array to make qsort() having n^2 time complexity?
I heard a long time ago that the implementation of the qsort function is the quick sorting algorithm and has a worst-case time complexity of n^2.
But recently when I was trying to construct a set of data that would allow the qsort function to time out, I discovered that its implementation is not exactly the same as the widely known quick sort algorithm, and that it uses many optimisation tricks.
For example, there is a comment in the glibc implementation
/* Select median value from among LO, MID, and HI. Rearrange
LO and HI so the three values are sorted. This lowers the
probability of picking a pathological pivot value and
skips a comparison for both the LEFT_PTR and RIGHT_PTR in
the while loops. */

So how to construct an array to make qsort() having n^2 time complexity? Although I have read the source code of qsort in glibc, I still can't come up with a constructor method.
I've tried ascending, descending and half up half down arrays, but none of these constructors work.
for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
{
    a[i] = i;
}
for (int i = N / 2; i < N; i++)
{
    a[i] = N - 1 - i;
}

and this
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (i & 1)
        a[N - 1 - i / 2] = i;
    else
        a[i / 2] = i;
}


Per the Wikipedia page, the worst case for partitioning occurs when one of the sublists is size n−1 for the first partition, n−2 for the second, and so on. So, take the C code for the implementation you are working with and figure out, by hand, how it chooses the first pivot. Then change every other element to be on one side of that pivot. Then figure out how it chooses the second pivot. Again change every other element in the first sublist to be on one side of the pivot. Repeat…

qsort() is not synonymous to "Quick Sort". The algorithm implement in a specific library is the choice of the implementors, not a requirement from the Standard.

… The GCC comment alludes to considering three elements, so you might only be able to change n−3 elements for the first sublist, having to leave 3 as they are for the pivot selection, and similarly for the remaining sublists, but it should still give you the worst case for that implementation.

This article, "A Killer Adversary for Quicksort" describes the process quite well. https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/mdmspe.pdf

There are Quicksort implementations that scale as O(n log n) in the worst case.  Those using median of medians pivot selection, for example.  There are also those that have near zero probability of going quadratic, and no predictable killer sequences, such as those relying on random pivot selection.

@user541686 I was going to discuss the implementation in glibc, but now Jim Mischel shared an article that gives a heuristic algorithm that is useful under almost all implementations. It's even better.

@EricPostpischil I did want to do this at first, but then I realized that my brain just couldn't keep up.

@user541686 "You're going to have to give a specific implementation to he able to discuss this" -- the question is tagged glibc and mentions it in the text -- that's the specific implementation.

Does glibc qsort() switch to heapsort once it gets past some level of recursion?

@rcgldr My reading of https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/qsort.c says no. The code manages an explicit stack and ensures that the smaller partition is always processed first. Also, below a certain threshold it uses insertion sort. But there's no alternate sorting method if the recursion gets too deep.

@JimMischel - so stack space complexity is limited to O(log(n)), but worst case time complexity remains at O(n^2). Processing smaller partition first dates back to Hoare's original quicksort where there was no native stack, so it was iterative and used a software stack that he called a "nest" at the time. Larger partition indexes were pushed on to the "nest", and the code looped back to process the smaller partition.  I don't know about Visual Studio's qsort(), but it's C++ std::sort() does switches to heap sort at some recursion level, limiting worst case time complexity to O(n log(n)).

@pmg You are right, after reading the glibc-2.40 source code, I find that the latest qsort() implementation actually uses heap sort and merge sort.
